# find any order of strings in regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have a web browser that show user selected website, then user can select part of the text on web browser and by `IHTMLDocument2` in mshtml I get html text of selected part. I need to extract the pattern of selected text for example html text of selected text is

```
href="/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&amp;Sect2=HITOFF&amp;p=1&amp;u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-   bool.html&amp;r=1&amp;f=G&amp;l=50&amp;co1=AND&amp;d=PTXT&amp;s1=auv&amp;OS=auv&     amp;RS=auv">9041</A>
```

my pattern is:

```
\s*href=".+?">.+?</a>
```

my problem is that in some html texts there are title,class,href etc,when i get html text by `IHTMLDocument2` the order for example is `title="..." class="..."` but when I read the content of page in web browser the order is `class="..." title="..."`. How can I use regular expression for building the pattern that the order is not important and find the patterns?

Comment: Use [**Html Agility Pack**](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for this instead.

Comment: I don't know why when I use htmltext, the text is different with source of page. i need a regex that when the order of html attributes change, can match and find them

Comment: @hwnd: that comment should be inserted automatically by the system every time it finds a question with "html" and "regex" in the same sentence.  Heck, SO could even initiate a download for it. :)

Comment: maybe my question isn't clear, i want a regex that match string1 and string2 but the order is not important, forexample match **title=".+?"\sclass=title3** or **class=title3\stitle=".+?"**